# Does the radix size used for radix sort algorithm matter in a practice?

Tags: sorting, memory, radix-sort

I've heard that the worst case memory scenario for radix sort is O(n+r) where n is the array size and r is the radix. But since it's rare to use anything more than base 16 in computing, does it really matter in practice whether r=2 or r=100? Is there any real impact on space?

Comment: Not sure why you're saying "it's rare to use anything more than base 16 in computing". What does that have to do with this?

Comment: In numbers, the base used is rarely above 16. I believe it can be 255 for ASCII, from [somewhere I read](https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/sorting/radix-sort-lsd/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be worst case space O(n + r logr(range)), where range is the range of values to be sorted. For example, for 64 bit integers range = 2^64, and if doing radix sort base 256 for 64 bit integers, log256(2^64) = 8, which is the number of radix sort passes needed. The worst case space usage is when a matrix for all passes is used, such as 8 by 256 matrix for sorting 64 bit unsigned integers base 256: matrix[8][256]. Worst case space overhead is the size of the temporary array used for radix sort = n elements plus the size of the matrix. For the example of 64 bit integers sorted base 256:

```
n + r · ceil(log256(2^64)) = n + 256 · 8.
```

Comment: Doesn't this essentially mean it has no real impact? Cause given the best use case of radix sort, I'd say 8x8x256 is definitely going to be way too negligible

Comment: @pintert3 - if base 65536 (2^26) is used, then the indexes | counts are stored in an 4 by 65536 by 8 or 4 by 65536 by 4 matrix, which uses more space than base 256.